# StandardSetController on object List view: Select All

Tags: apex, visualforce, list-view, standardsetcontroller

Imagine a custom object called 'Foo' which is having the normal SFDC tab displaying the SFDC OOTB list view page. From this page, you can select, create, ... different views and return a list of matching records.

On the Tab List view page, I would like to add a custom button which deletes the records which are selected in the list view. Fairly easy using the **StandardSetController** and method **getSelected()**.

The **standard** tab **List View page** has a 'Select All' checkbox selecting all the records on the current page from the list view. What I would like to do in my custom extension is **capturing** if the checkbox 'Select All' has been checked. If that checkbox has been marked, then capture *all* the records from the list view, not only the one's selected on the current page.

### **Purpose**

The button should delete the records:

- Which are selected on the page(s)
- Or all the records on all pages if checkbox 'Select All' has been checked

This would allow us to still configure, in the normal way, the list view.

### **Question**

Is this feasible without creating a custom VF page?

### **Alternative**

Generating a second button which calls an extension function using the next functionality from the StandardSetController, thus getting all the records in the filtered view